# How to configure multiple instances in Jmeter from command prompt (Non-GUI)

Tags: jmeter, instance, command-prompt

Want to create multiple instances to run my code from command prompt but unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for distributed testing documentation?

- [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Also there are some wrapper scripts like [JMeter ec2 Script](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2), [Docker images](https://github.com/pedrocesar-ti/distributed-jmeter-docker), [Kubernetes configurations](https://github.com/kubernauts/jmeter-kubernetes), etc.